# Create a portable USB applications within a Linux installation along with it

Tags: linux

I have questions
I'm an kubuntu on our system And a series of programs on it I like postgres
I liked this system And I want it on my USB flash memory to on any system that wanted to bring it up and use it as live، backup do not want it but want it to be portable .
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

#### How to make a Kubuntu live USB using Startup Disk Creator

Kubuntu has a built-in application for creating a bootable live USB for installing/running live Ubuntu (or Ubuntu flavor, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, ...) called *Startup Disk Creator*. You can find Startup Disk Creator in the Application Launcher.

The USB flash drive that you use with Startup Disk Creator should be 2GB or larger. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later it should be 4GB or larger. Startup Disk Creator will automatically format your USB flash drive to FAT32 and make it bootable. If you have only one USB flash drive plugged in to your computer, Startup Disk Creator will select it automatically. Be **very careful** to select the USB flash drive in the Make Startup Disk window in order to avoid overwriting the partition which Kubuntu is installed on, which may make Kubuntu unbootable. In the screenshot below you can see how the USB flash drive Device is identified by its model name, the same model name that appears under the **Drive** heading after *Model:* in the Disks (disk utility) application.

[image: Startup Disk Creator]
<sup>**Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 16.04**</sup>

You can also move the *Stored in reserved extra space* slider back and forth to create some reserved extra space for persistent file storage across reboots. This will enable you to install applications in the Kubuntu live USB, and the applications that you install will be saved persistently across reboots. How much persistent file storage space you need depends on how many applications you want to install and how many files you want to save on the USB drive, but you will soon use up all the available space on the USB drive unless you start off with a USB drive that has at least 4GB.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later Startup Disk Creator no longer has the persistent file storage option.